# How to store list of register base addresses in a static class member and count them?

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, cpu-registers

I'm working with microcontrollers for embedded devices. These controllers provide multiple peripherals which a configured and controlled using registers. A peripheral usually has a certain register set associated with it. Several peripherals of the same type (e.g., Timer0, Timer1, ...) have the same register set but they are located at different base addresses.

Usually the manufacturer provides header files that define the registers and related addresses for each peripheral.

For example, this header file for a timer peripheral could be provided:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t IR;                                
  uint32_t TCR;                              
  uint32_t TC;                               
  uint32_t MCR;                              
  uint32_t MR[4];                            
} CTIMER_Type;

#define CTIMER0_BASE                             (0x40008000u)
#define CTIMER0                                  ((CTIMER_Type *)CTIMER0_BASE)
#define CTIMER1_BASE                             (0x40009000u)
#define CTIMER1                                  ((CTIMER_Type *)CTIMER1_BASE)
#define CTIMER_BASE_PTRS                         { CTIMER0, CTIMER1 }
```

These header files are specific for a certain device. In this example, information about a timer peripheral is provided: there are two timers and their register set are located at `CTIMER0 a`
nd `CTIMER1`, respectively.

**Using C**, I'd pull  the list of base register addresses `CTIMER_BASE_PTRS` into my implementation using:

```
static CTIMER_Type * ctimers[] =  CTIMER_BASE_PTRS;
static int timers_count = sizeof(ctimers)/sizeof(*ctimers);
```

**Now using C++**, I want to write a driver class and include the list of available timers `CTIMER_BASE_PTRS` in my code. Also I want to calculate the number of timers available.

I came up with this code which you can [try for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/YxGa1nfP1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdint.h>

/* usually provided by chip manufacturer through chip specific include file */
typedef struct {
  uint32_t IR;                                
  uint32_t TCR;                              
  uint32_t TC;                               
  uint32_t MCR;                              
  uint32_t MR[4];                            
} CTIMER_Type;

#define CTIMER0_BASE                             (0x40008000u)
#define CTIMER0                                  ((CTIMER_Type *)CTIMER0_BASE)
#define CTIMER1_BASE                             (0x40009000u)
#define CTIMER1                                  ((CTIMER_Type *)CTIMER1_BASE)
#define CTIMER_BASE_PTRS                         { CTIMER0, CTIMER1 }
/* end manufacturer include file */

static CTIMER_Type * ctimers[] =  CTIMER_BASE_PTRS;

class TimerDriver_base  {
public:
    TimerDriver_base() {
        printf("No of timers available:%i\n", timers_count);
    }
private:
     constexpr static int timers_count = sizeof(ctimers)/sizeof(*ctimers);
    
    // A
    // uncommenting next line prompts compiler error: 'reinterpret_cast' from integer to pointer
    //constexpr static CTIMER_Type * ctimers1[] =  CTIMER_BASE_PTRS;

    // B
    static CTIMER_Type * ctimers2[];
    // uncommenting next line prompts compiler error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'CTIMER_Type* []'
    // constexpr static int timers_count2 = sizeof(ctimers2)/sizeof(*ctimers2);

};

// B
CTIMER_Type * TimerDriver_base::ctimers2[] =  CTIMER_BASE_PTRS;

int main()
{
    TimerDriver_base MyTimer;
}
```

I tried to include the list of timers `ctimers[]` into the driver class using two approaches:

A) using the define `CTIMER_BASE_PTRS` to initialize a static constexpr. That failed - seemingly as C++ does not allow the cast in the constexpr.

B) using the define `CTIMER_BASE_PTRS` to initialize a static array of pointers. That's ok, however, I can not calculate the size of it.

As both approaches failed, I resorted to a static global variable (as in the C code). But that's probably due to my limited proficiency in C++. Thus I'd like to know:

**How do I do define a the list of drivers `ctimers[]` inside a class and calculate the length of the list?**

Thanks.
Dan

Comment: OT: The fact that the initial values are base addresses of multiple instances of objects is not relevant for your issue. However, I appreciate your description of the background.

Comment: the first problem is actually constexpr which would exist even outside of class, the second is declaration without size.

Answer (score 1):

as `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed in constant expression, both would fail*

---

you can use `inline static` instead.

I'd also use c++ container (but raw array would work as well).

```cpp
struct TimerDriver_base  {
    inline static std::array ctimers2 = CTIMER_BASE_PTRS;
    static constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<decltype(ctimers2)>::value;
    // size is also accessible as `TimerDriver_base::ctimers2.size()`
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4eq9j79fY

---

---

* if you change the namespace scope one to this it'd also fail

```
static constexpr CTIMER_Type * ctimers[] =  CTIMER_BASE_PTRS;
```